# Create table with partition syntax error : MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, create-table

I have an error in creating `MySQL` table with partitioning.

```
    CREATE TABLE employees (
    context VARCHAR(25),
    id INT
)
PARTITION BY LIST(context) (
    PARTITION pNorth VALUES IN('ads','asd')
);
```

It gives:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): VALUES value must be of same type as partition function near ''asd')
>       )' at line 6

Please help me out.

Comment: please read this http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html

Comment: Error is because in PARTITION BY LIST(expr) each partition is defined by means of a VALUES IN (value_list), where value_list is a comma-separated list of integers.You can refer here for details:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to partition on a `VARCHAR` data type column. For a `LIST` partition you must reference an `INTEGER` type column. From [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-list.html):

> List partitioning in MySQL is similar to range partitioning in many
>   ways. As in partitioning by RANGE, each partition must be explicitly
>   defined. The chief difference between the two types of partitioning is
>   that, in list partitioning, each partition is defined and selected
>   based on the membership of a column value in one of a set of value
>   lists, rather than in one of a set of contiguous ranges of values.
>   This is done by using PARTITION BY LIST(expr) where expr is a column
>   value or an expression based on a column value and returning an
>   integer value, and then defining each partition by means of a VALUES
>   IN (value_list), where value_list is a comma-separated list of
>   integers.

Misleading error though for sure!

***EDIT***

What you should take a look at is partitioning by `LIST COLUMNS` as opposed to partitioning via `LIST`. Hence:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    context VARCHAR(25),
    id INT
)
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(context) (
    PARTITION pNorth VALUES IN('ads','asd')
);
```

Comment: @Deepshikha, .. But how about the first example given in this doc. > https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html  . It appears value_list in this contains strings.

Comment: +1 correct. In MySQL 5.1, you can do LIST partitioning only with integers. In MySQL 5.5, they added the capability to do LIST COLUMNS with some other data types. It is recommended to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bill Karwin pointed it out..
"In MySQL 5.1, you can do LIST partitioning only with integers. In MySQL 5.5, they added the capability to do LIST COLUMNS with some other data types."

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for LIST partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-management-range-list.html) does not mention `COLUMNS` as a keyword.
Try removing `COLUMNS` from your query:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
)
PARTITION BY LIST (context) (
  PARTITION pNorth VALUES IN('ads','asd')
)
```

Comment: [LIST COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html) was introduced in MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find there is no performance advantage of `BY LIST` over a suitable INDEX.

[More Partition discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).